# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided in Heroku (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, internal-server-error, mern

So I got my MERN app and I wanna upload it in Heroku.

All good until I visit my Heroku app URL and in logs, I get this error: `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided`

I would use `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` but i am using react - MERN.

Nodejs:

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const passport = require('./passport/');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb', {useNewUrlParser: true})
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'secret here',
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/authentication', usersRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"))
    })
}


app.listen(PORT);

module.exports = app
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

-Thanks a ton

Comment: show your nodejs server code

Comment: Done thanks for help

Comment: Ohno, I had an upload time cooldown the couldn't upload the code :(

Comment: Is the error in the ```res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"))``` statement?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Should it be ```res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "client", "build", "index.html"))``` instead?

Comment: Lemme try one minute

Comment: Would you like a screenshot of my files?

Comment: Yes that'd be helpful.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7dde7010d594dd17f8331bac57ab0b49 @zS1L3NT

Comment: @zS1L3NT It didnt work any other solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213359/discussion-between-zs1l3nt-and-herpryth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write it on your package.json like this :

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
}

Replace node and npm with what you need and the same version you have in local.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))` instead because using __dirname goes to the main directory

Comment: Okay i will try and let you know!

Comment: Show your package.json